# defining a polygon interval for shading under a normal curve

Tags: r, plot

I am using some fairly simple code to produce the following image:

```
mean=1000
sd=200
Score <- round ((seq(-3,3,length=120)*sd + mean), -1)
y <- dnorm(Score,mean,sd)
data <- data.frame
plot(Score, y, type="l")
polygon(c( Score[Score>=1250], 1250 ),  c(y[Score>=1250],0 ), col="skyblue")
percentile <- round(pnorm((Score-mean)/sd)*100,2)
```

[image]

My problem is that the polygon is skewed. I know that my error is in how I have defined my polygon, but I don't know how to define its area as an interval between 1250-1600 rather than just greater or equal to 1250 (even though 1600 is the maximum score with the code I have).

Also, I have tried to translate this code into ggplot2 and have miserably failed. Any help with that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I replace `0` with `min(y[Score>=1250])`. It looks fine now.

```
mean=1000
sd=200
Score <- round ((seq(-3,3,length=120)*sd + mean), -1)
y <- dnorm(Score,mean,sd)
plot(Score, y, type="l")
polygon(c( Score[Score>=1250], 1250 ),  c(y[Score>=1250], min(y[Score>=1250])), col="skyblue")
percentile <- round(pnorm((Score-mean)/sd)*100,2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick and easy fix. If it had been a snake, I would have been bit.

Comment: @JWH2006 Glad to help. Please consider to accept the post you think solving this question as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather see you insert an additional point to show the correct height above zero.

```
plot(Score, y, type="l")
polygon(c( Score[Score>=1250], max(Score), 1250 ), 
        c(y[Score>=1250],0, 0 ), col="skyblue")
```

[image: Area under curve]